# Visual Studio - find and replace with regex with line breaks

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

Let's say I have some strings with line breaks in the wrong order, `\n\r`. If I find `(?<!\\r)\\n\\r` with regex ("`\n\r` not preceded by `\r`") and replace with `\r\n`, the replacement will be an actual line break instead of the four characters `\r\n`. But if I replace with `\\r\\n`, I get six characters instead of four. The replacement string seems to be interpreted as some sort of "semi-regex" where `\r` and  `\n` are recognized as special characters but `\\` is not.

Notepad++ and Eclipse do not work this way, as they replace regex with regex. Is there some way to tell Visual Studio either to replace regex with regex or regex with plain text?

Comment: Is this for code or is this just editing a text file using visual-studio? If code, please provide which language you're writing in and can you provide the code you're trying, expected input, and the expected result? I'm guessing something is going on with the '\' being an escape character in Regex and whatever code language you're using

Comment: It's a C++ project, although the result is the same if the characters occur outside the context of a string, or in any xml or other text file in the solution. For a concrete example, I want e.g. `"A\n\rB"` replaced with `"A\r\nB"`, instead I get `"A[line break]B"` or `"A\\r\\nB"`.

Comment: So, replace `(?<!\\r)(\\n)(\\r)` with `$2$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you noted, Visual Studio uses this "semi-regex" in the replacement string. I had to solve it in my VS extension [Multiline Search and Replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterMacej.MultilineSearchandReplace&ssr=false#overview). I have documented it in detail in `ConvertReplaceWithToRegEx` and `ConvertFindWhatToRegEx` methods in [MultilineSearchReplace.cs](https://github.com/PeterMacej/multiline-search-vs/blob/main/MultiLineSearch.Shared/SearchReplace/MultilineSearchReplace.cs).

The following rules apply to the replacement string (this is what I have observed). And the workaround that I used:

- The `$` is used for group replacement.
- `$$` should be used for replacing with `$` literal. But this only works if any group replacement (e.g., `$1`, `$+`, ...) is also present in the replace string. So replace with `$$ $1` works but simple `$$` inserts two $$. We need to use the trick described below for \r and always use `$+$`.
- All other characters are treated as literals, except for `\r` `\n` and `\t`. All other combinations are OK.
- The `\\` doesn't work for escaping the `\` character. So we cannot escape `\r` with `\\r`. We need to use more complicated `\$+r`, where again, the `$+` substitutes the last group (which needs to be defined in 'Find what' and must be empty). This is important if we want to replace with a text like:

`C:\MyFolder\root\nextLevel\test`

Without escaping we would get:

```
C:\MyFolder
oot
extLevel  est
```

As already mentioned, for the trick with the `$+` to work, you need to add an empty group `()` at the end of the 'Find what' string.

Comment: So using your example from your comment. To replace `A\n\rB` with `A\r\nB`, the Find what should be `A\\n\\rB()` and Replace with should be `A\$+r\$+nB`.

Comment: Well it's `\n\r` I wanna replace in any context other than as in several correct line breaks in a row `\r\n\r\n`, so it would be `(?<!\\r)\\n\\r()` replaced with `\$+r\$+n`.